# C# Get URL after a redirect x seconds after initial call

Tags: c#, redirect, webclient

Scenario goes like this:

- I call a URL from C#, using WebClient or HttpWebRequest
  This gives me a 200 OK Return OK and a Website saying something like "checking... please wait"
- After about 2 seconds I am redirected to another URL (via a 302 return code) - the URL I am being redirected to is what I Need to catch in C#

Problem is that from what I found out something like WebClient.OpenRead or HttpWebRequest.GetResponse only Returns the immediate answer from the webserver which is just the first "200 OK please wait" page.

How can I make the Client wait for the Redirect to happen and then fetch the new URL?

Comment: That's Javascript, not a 302.

Comment: Sounds like it's a HTML/Javascript redirect, you'd probably want something that can run that like Awesomium instead.

Comment: I'm just guessing but when you are programming at the http layer you have to implement ways to handle things like this on the client side.  The original get request was to a specific URL which was redirected by the server.  There is a property in the HTTPRequest you may be able to use.  Check it out here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for the replies. It is a 302 indeed (seen it with wireshark), but as its delayed and sent AFTER a 200 code (most likely done via JavaScript on the server side) i cannot capture that in my app. I would assume this needs some more low-level call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the obscure remote site redirect handling it was only possible to solve this using a lower level communication using TCPClient and NetworkStream and thus it was possible to capture all necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

```
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
```

Please see 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks that's what I thought might to the trick too, but as far as I can see this only works if you get the redirect as a direct response from the server and not when its delayed after you get normal return codes and an intermediate HTML-page in between